# implode не разбирает массив

Tags: php

```
$diametr  = "диаметр деталей составляет 2,5 ММ, 5 ММ 4,5 ММ)";
$diametr  = preg_match_all('/[0-9\.\,]+(?=\s?мм)/ui', $diametr, $diametr_result);

print_r($diametr_result);

$diametr_result = implode(" ", $diametr_result);
```

не могу понять, почему implode не разбирает массив и не выводит строку со значениями "2,5 5 4,5"?

PS
результат print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2,5
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 4,5
        )

)
```

*(вижу что вопрос тупой, но многомерные массивы разбираются в некоторых случаях, здесь же никак)*

Comment: Добавьте результат `print_r($diametr_result);` в вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас эти элементы лежат в первом элементе результирующего массива

```
$diametr_result = implode(" ", $diametr_result[0]);
```

Comment: спасибо! ситуация стала яснее. правда не понимаю, когда в многомерных находит то что нужно без указания элементов, просто находит данные через регулярку..

Comment: @Amsterdam пожалуйста переформулируйте комментарий, что осталось не решённым, не совсем ясно.

Comment: @AlexKnow скорее, нужно будет задать отдельный вопрос с примером, для комментария многовато будет. Поэтому, тут, спасибо всем за ответы, задача по конкретному вопросу решена!

Comment: @AlexKnow вот такая проблема возникает с массивом побольше: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1126414/Массив-через-preg-match-all