# Массив через preg_match_all

Tags: php

Переменная **$diametr** получает такой массив:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => DiDom\Element Object (
        [node:protected] => DOMElement Object ( 
            [tagName] => div 
            [schemaTypeInfo] => 
            [nodeName] => div 
            [nodeValue] => металл 20 см (3 мм)
            [nodeType] => 1 
            [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
            [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
            [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
            [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
            [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
            [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
            [attributes] => (object value omitted)
            [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
            [namespaceURI] => 
            [prefix] => 
            [localName] => div 
            [baseURI] => 
            [textContent] => металл 20 см (3 мм) 
        )
        [classAttribute:protected] => 
        [styleAttribute:protected] => 
    )
    [1] => DiDom\Element Object ( 
        [node:protected] => DOMElement Object ( 
            [tagName] => div 
            [schemaTypeInfo] => 
            [nodeName] => div 
            [nodeValue] => металл 20 см (3,5 мм)
            [nodeType] => 1 
            [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
            [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
            [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
            [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
            [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
            [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
            [attributes] => (object value omitted)
            [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
            [namespaceURI] => 
            [prefix] => 
            [localName] => div 
            [baseURI] => 
            [textContent] => металл 20 см (3,5 мм) 
        )
        [classAttribute:protected] => 
        [styleAttribute:protected] => 
    )
    [2] => DiDom\Element Object ( 
        [node:protected] => DOMElement Object ( 
            [tagName] => div 
            [schemaTypeInfo] => 
            [nodeName] => div 
            [nodeValue] => металл 20 см (4 мм)
            [nodeType] => 1 
            [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
            [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
            [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
            [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
            [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
            [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
            [attributes] => (object value omitted)
            [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
            [namespaceURI] => 
            [prefix] => 
            [localName] => div 
            [baseURI] => 
            [textContent] => металл 20 см (4 мм) 
        )
        [classAttribute:protected] => 
        [styleAttribute:protected] => 
    ) 
)
```

через preg_match_all пытаюсь получить **все** значения "цифра+мм" и передать значение в **$diametr_result**:

```
$diametr  = preg_match_all('/[0-9\.\,]+(?=\s?мм)/ui', $diametr, $diametr_result);
$diametr_result = implode(" ", $diametr_result);
```

Регулярка правильная, на одиночном примере отрабатывает, Но почему-то не может найти значения в этом массиве. Что я упускаю?

Comment: А где вы видели, что вместо строки в `preg_match_all` можно пихать массив объектов?

Comment: @ArchDemon в чем ключевая разница с этим примером?: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125882/implode-не-разбирает-массив?noredirect=1&lq=1 , пытаюсь понять. Благодарен буду за конкретную подсказку

Comment: В том что там матчится строка, а здесь массив объектов?

Comment: @u_mulder допустим, но задачу то как решить? Массив преобразовать в строку? Будут ли у вас предложения? У меня не получается это сделать чз implode

Comment: Объект можно cериализовать: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php. По типу данных это будет string.

Comment: Можно реализовать интерфейс ArrayAccess, который обеспечивает доступ к объектам как к массивам (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.arrayaccess.php#class.arrayaccess). Потом использовать implode

Comment: Можно в классе  реализовать метод __toString() с механизмом преобразования в строку (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

Comment: Это парсер? Так вы и разбивайте нужные вам значения, зачем вы обходите все? Вам или текстКонтекст надо или нодВалъю, их и обходите регуляркой

Comment: @Walfter верно, это парсер. В теории все звучит понятно, но у меня проблемы с практикой, не получается. Теории в комментариях набросали много, и я это ценю, но хоть бы один живой пример, было бы вообще замечательно)

Comment: @Amsterdam дайте пример строки и что надо на выходе, выведу Вам

Comment: @AlexKnow получить данные из textContent, их обработать регуляркой

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
<?php 

$items = [];

//получаем данные из строк
foreach ($diametr as $value) {

    preg_match('/[0-9\.\,]+(?=\s?мм)/ui', $value->node->textContent, $diametr_result);

    foreach ($diametr_result as $result) {
        $items[] = $result;
    }
}

$diametr_result = implode(" ", $items);
```

Comment: я правильно понял, это, то, что вам нужно?

Comment: не выводит никакие данные. Может быть я не правильно использую конструкцию http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a055af366578ac15577eb038b3c73230290d84b0

Comment: @Amsterdam ну вы мой код опять и прислали, что конкретно не работает, у себя выполнил получилось "3 3,5 3,5 4 "

Comment: да, ваш код я и пробую, но данные не выводит. Что то я совсем запутался..не могли бы вы показать ваш работающий вариант в песочнице?

Comment: @Amsterdam вот код, за основу взята структура вашего объекта из примера. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a6742428eedc25c53035fbf2778d7bc944fb779

Comment: но конкретно из массива я не могу получить данные