# preg_match_all выводит количество совпадений вместо результата

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Регулярка ищет совпадения по "цифра+мм", находит их

```
$diametr = '<div>металл толщиной 15 мм 2 мм 3мм</div>';

$diametr_result  = preg_match_all('/[0-9\.\,]+(?=\s?мм)/ui', $diametr, $diametr_result);
$diametr_result = preg_replace('/[^0-9\,\.]/', " ", $diametr_result);

echo $diametr_result;
```

Но выводит не найденные числа, а количество найденных совпадений по шаблону. Почему так? Как вывести найденные значения а не их количество?

В данном случае результат выдает просто "3" (кол-во совпадений). А нужно вывести "15 2 3"

Comment: спасибо за минус, все сразу стало ясно

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: @splash58 разве не очевидно, что документацию я не мог не читать, но не разобрался с ней? поэтому пришел сюда с просьбой объяснения более внятного, в идеале живого примера. потому что через implode отдаваемый массив тоже не обрабатывается, и я не могу понять как со всем этим работать

Comment: Все через переназначение в одну переменную, а если result уже массив, а не строка?

Comment: @Yurij и что тогда вы предлагаете сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$diametr_result  = preg_match_all('/[0-9\.\,]+(?=\s?мм)/ui', $diametr, $diametr_result);`

Смотри, что ты делаешь в этой строке:
ты передаёшь ссылку на переменную $diametr_result в функцию preg_match_all (третий параметр). Смотрим документацию и видим, что третьим параметром надо передать переменную, в которую будут записаны результаты работы функции.

А потом ты берёшь и присваиваешь этой же переменной то, что функция вернёт. Смотрим, опять же, документацию, и читаем, что функция возвращает количество найденных вариантов.

То есть - сначала в эту переменную записывается то, что функция нашла. А потом (результат-то у нас возвращается ПОСЛЕ работы функции. То есть - сначала работает функция, что-то там делает и в процессе своей работы записывает в переменную то, что нашла) в эту же переменную записывается то, что функция вернула.

В общем, самое простое, что ты можешь сделать:

`preg_match_all('/[0-9\.\,]+(?=\s?мм)/ui', $diametr, $diametr_result);`

Это перестать перезаписывать результат, который тебе функция записала в переменную.
Ну а если тебе нужно количество - то записывать это в другую переменную:

`$diametr_count_result  = preg_match_all('/[0-9\.\,]+(?=\s?мм)/ui', $diametr, $diametr_result);`

И тогда в `$diametr_result` будет то, что функция нашла, а в  `$diametr_count_result` будет количество найденного.

Comment: спасибо за развернутое объяснение, именно это и хотелось бы услышать! Такие ответы дорогого стоят

Answer (score 0):

В общем задача решилась следующим образом (уверен, подобное решение очевидно для знающих людей и пишется быстрее, чем найти и прикрепить ссылку на документацию):

```
$diametr = '<div>металл толщиной 15 мм 2 мм 3мм</div>';

$diametr  = preg_match_all('/[0-9\.\,]+(?=\s?мм)/', $diametr, $diametr_result); 
$diametr_result = implode(" ", $diametr_result[0]);

echo $diametr_result;
```

Признаться, решил интуитивным образом, так и не разобравшись в сути, к сожалению

Comment: странно. вчера вроде поблагодарил за развернутое объяснение, а сегодня снова так и не разобрался.

Comment: И даже после всех объяснений все равно - переменная $diametr зачем-то перезаписывается, но потом больше нигде не используется. Какая-то обсессивная мания присваивать уже существующей переменной не нужный тебе результат функции

Comment: А, главное, "задача решилась" [ещё неделю назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1127350/179379)

Comment: @Ипатьев это я написал полчаса назад, а ответ, за который поблагодарил, увидел после обновления страницы, когда опубликовал свой. То что было неделю назад, я не смог применить к реальному массиву, не выводило оно данных. А что бы избавиться от "обсессивных маний", здесь и задаю вопросы, чтобы понять, как делать правильно. Но с этим вопросом что то на одни минусы сообщество было щедрым

Comment: Обращение к элементу массива не имеет ни малейшего отношения к работе с этим элементом. Решение проблемы с регуляркой ты получил неделю назад. Но по какой-то причине сейчас выдаешь его за полученное в муках самостойтельно

Comment: @Ипатьев причем здесь регулярка? Вопрос что неделю назад, что сейчас, был не в ней в принципе, прочти внимательней (раз мы перешли на "ты"). Там в теле вопроса даже написано "регулярка правильная". "Пролема" была в выводе данных из массива и использования preg_match_all

Comment: и как ответ недельной давности я мог выдавать сейчас за свой, если там ни одна строка кода не совпадает с тем, что я написал выше